# Which statistical test do I use?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing

I am running a study but am unsure which analysis to run. My study involves changing attitudes where participants will be given a questionnaire (on a scale of 1= strongly disagree, 5= strongly agree, etc.), then put in one of 4 conditions (each person in 1 condition only) then given the questionnaire again to see if attitudes are more likely to be changed by a certain condition. Which test is appropriate for this? Please help!

Comment: You haven't described any data related to attitudes, so it looks like you can't do anything.  Did you perhaps leave out some information about the data you will collect?

Comment: I have edited this now thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to find After$-$Before differences `d1`, ..., `d4` for the four
groups. Then do a Kruskal-Wallis nonparamatric test do see whether locations of
the differences are greater in some groups than in others.

For example, suppose counts of differences in Likert scores for the four groups (100 in each group) are as below. [Computations use R.]

```
table(d1)
d1
-2 -1  0  1  2 
 8 20 48 15  9 
table(d2)
d2
-2 -1  0  1  2 
14 15 15 24 32 
table(d3)
d3
-2 -1  0  1  2 
 8 11 22 29 30 
table(d4)
d4
-2 -1  0  1  2 
 4 10  2 41 43
```

Then a Kruskal-Wallis test gives a highly significant result, with a P-value very nearly $0.$

```
d = c(d1,d2,d3,d4); g=rep(1:4, each=100)
kruskal.test(d~g)

        Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  d by g
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 47.327, df = 3, p-value = 2.961e-10
```

Then, in order to see the pattern of differences among the groups, you
could do two-sample Wilcoxon (rank sum) tests on pairs of groups *ad hoc.* Using
the Bonferroni method for avoiding false discovery, you might consider
differences as significant if P-values are below 1%.

For example Groups 1 and 2, and Groups 3 and 4, differ significantly, but
Groups 2 and 3 do not.

```
wilcox.test(d1,d2)$p.val
[1] 0.003413176
wilcox.test(d2,d3)$p.val
[1] 0.5473373
wilcox.test(d3,d4)$p.val
[1] 0.003390662
```

*Notes:* (1) Suppose you believe it makes sense to interpret your Likert scores as
interval-numerical (and moreover to assume differences are roughly normal), instead of ordinal categories. Then you might use `oneway.test` in R (which assumes normal data, but does not assume group variances to be equal),
and, subsequently, use Welch two-sample t tests _ad hoc. [Conclusions about significant
differences for my fake data are about the same.] Both methods work for unequal numbers of subjects in the four groups.

The time to decide on the method of analysis is *before* you get data. It is
bad practice to do both nonparametric and nonparametric analyses and report
the one with the smaller P-value.

(2) In case you want them, here is the R code by which I simulated group differences
for my example above.

```
set.seed(810);  n = 100
d1 = sample(-2:2, n, rep=T, p=c(1,2,5,2,1))
d2 = sample(-2:2, n, rep=T, p=1:5)
d3 = sample(-2:2, n, rep=T, p=c(1,1,2,2,2))
d4 = sample(-2:2, n, rep=T, p=c(1,1,1,5,6))
```

I have programmed some fairly large differences among the groups.
With multiple runs (no `set.seed`) $n=100$ and $n=50$ subjects
per group almost always lead to rejection of the K-W null hypothesis.
Not quite so frequently with $n = 25.$

Comment: To apply a test to the differences you would need to assume the Likert responses are interval so that (i) "5"-"2"=="4"-"1" and (ii) "5" - "3" == "4" - "2" == "3"-1" and (iii) "5"-"4" == "4"-"3" == "3"-"2" == "2"-"1" ...  (I'm not objecting to making that assumption *per se*, but it should be clear that it's needed before computing such differences. Without that assumption, something could still be done, but it's more complicated)

Comment: @Glen_b: Yes, thanks. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. I have only ever come across Wilcoxon and bonferroni during my studies so I will definitely have to research kruskal Wallis thank you. Would this only be a suitable test when data is non-parametric?

Comment: Data don't have parameters and so are neither "parametric" nor "nonparametric". Models have parameters - so models, and procedures based on them, may be described as [parametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_statistics) or non-parametric (or perhaps something else again, such as semi-parametric). If you mean instead "would this *only* be a suitable test when the population distribution from which the sample was drawn is non-normal?" then in general you don't *know* that's the case (though sometimes you can be quite sure that it isn't the case, such as with Likert items)... ctd

Comment: ctd ... though if the distribution seems as if it might be fairly close to normal, the Kruskal Wallis can still perform fairly well.